# How to display all the records with their properties in another db?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display all the phones and their users's info's in a table but I keep getting this error:

***Undefined property: stdClass::$user***

When I check it on tinker it retrives the user without problem but I can't perform the same thing in blade file.

I have table of

`users`

id | name | surname | email | password | department_id

and `ip_phones`

user_id | ip_adress | mac_adress | phone_number

This is my UserController

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(IpPhone::class);
    }

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
```

This is my IpPhonesController:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IpPhone extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is HomeController

```
    public function list()
    {
        $phones = DB::table('ip_phones')->get(); 

        return view('list', compact('phones'));
    }
```

And this is list.blade.php file

```
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>IP</th>
     <th>MAC</th>
     <th>UserName</th>
     <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($phones as $phone)
  <tr>
   <td>{{$phone->ip_adress}}</td>
   <td>{{$phone->mac_adress}}</td>
   <td>{{$phone->user->name}}</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>

  @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mentioned, I've tried it but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use eloquent.

Change this

```
DB::table('ip_phones')->get();
```

to;

```
IpPhone::with('user')->get();
```

then it should work.

Comment: You are welcome, you can confirm or upvote reply, so others can know this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function list()
    {
        $data['phone'] = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('ip_phone','users.id', '=', 'ip_phone.user_id ')
        ->get(); 

        return view('list', $data);
    }
```

//blade

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>IP</th>
     <th>MAC</th>
     <th>UserName</th>
     <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($phones as $phone)
  <tr>
   <td>{{$phone->ip_adress}}</td>
   <td>{{$phone->mac_adress}}</td>
   <td>{{$phone->name}}</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>

  @endforeach
 </tbody>
</table>
```